# Invalid Use of a Group Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been looking for a solution to this seemingly simple problem.  The query only breaks when I introduce the last sum() function in the where clause.  I get the error "*Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function.*"  I can't figure out why it won't allow me to make this one where statement.

**Query**

```
select 
    dIntervalStart,
    weekofyear(dIntervalStart) WeekOfYear,
    weekday(dIntervalStart) DayOfWeek,
    cast(dIntervalStart as time) IntervalStart,
    sum(nExternToInternAcdCalls) CallVolume
from
    iwrkgrpqueuestats
where
    SiteId = 1
        and cname in ('applications' , 'employer',
        'factfind',
        'general',
        'other')
        and cReportGroup = '*'
        and CAST(dIntervalStart as time) between '07:00' and '17:30'
        and weekday(dIntervalStart) not in (5 , 6)
        and sum(nExternToInternAcdCalls) <> 0
group by weekofyear(dIntervalStart) , weekday(dIntervalStart) , cast(dIntervalStart as time)
order by IntervalStart asc, dIntervalStart desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relocate the predicate on the aggregate expression to the **`HAVING`** clause, e.g.:

```
 GROUP BY ...
HAVING sum(nExternToInternAcdCalls) <> 0
 ORDER BY ...
```

The predicates in the WHERE clause are evaluated when rows are accessed, they pick out which rows are included. The value of the aggregate expression (e.g. **`SUM(foo)`**) isn't available when the rows are accessed. The value for that expression can't be determined until *after* the rows are accessed.

The predicates in the `HAVING` clause are applied after the rows are accessed, and after the resultset is prepared. When the HAVING predicates are evaluated, the aggregate (`SUM(foo)`) will be available.

---

NOTE: the `GROUP BY` clause would typically include all of the non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list. MySQL is more relaxed than other databases, which can be both a blessing and a curse; if the GROUP BY "collapses" rows, for non-aggregates in the SELECT list, MySQL returns a value from *one* of the rows.

That is, if you GROUP BY `weekofyear(foo)`, and return `foo` in the SELECT list, and there are multiple rows with foo values that evaluate to the same `weekofyear(foo)` value, MySQL will return one row for the given `weekofyear(foo)` and also return *one* of the foo values from *one* of the rows. Other databases (Oracle, SQL Server, et al.) would throw an error rather than returning a resultset.

Comment: Thank you.  I was under the assumption that you had to have the function in the group by clause before it could be placed in the having clause.

Comment: @Neggly: I think any predicate that's valid in the `WHERE` clause is also valid in the `HAVING` clause. But because of *when* those predicates are evaluated (as described in my answer), its beneficial  from a performance standpoint, to have the predicates in the WHERE clause to "filter out" as many rows as possible, and allow MySQL to use indexes, etc. The `HAVING` clause gets evaluated nearly last in the execution plan, after all the rows have been accessed and prepared.

Comment: Can you tell me if it's more performance to use `HAVING` or to use _a Subqueries in the FROM Clause_ like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) WHERE CallVolume <> 0` where CallVolume is the sum(..) ?

Comment: @Ryx5: MySQL materializes all views (inline and stored). (I believe that's still true up through 5.5.) And MySQL does not push predicates from  an outer query down into a view query. MySQL runs the view query and populates a temporary MyISAM table (MySQL calls it a "derived table"), and the outer query runs against the temporary table. In most cases, I think that the `HAVING` would have a very slight edge in terms of performance, because I think it can operate on the generated resultset. The inline view version forces MySQL to use two copies: the "derived table" and then the final resultset.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `group by` like this, group by is used to distinct result and and specify the element of reference of aggregate functions

Try this :

```
select 
    dIntervalStart,
    weekofyear(dIntervalStart) WeekOfYear,
    weekday(dIntervalStart) DayOfWeek,
    cast(dIntervalStart as time) IntervalStart,
    sum(nExternToInternAcdCalls) CallVolume
from
    iwrkgrpqueuestats
where
    SiteId = 1
        and cname in ('applications' , 'employer',
        'factfind',
        'general',
        'other')
        and cReportGroup = '*'
        and CAST(dIntervalStart as time) between '07:00' and '17:30'
        and weekday(dIntervalStart) not in (5 , 6)
        and sum(nExternToInternAcdCalls) <> 0
group by dIntervalStart,
        WeekOfYear,
        DayOfWeek,
        IntervalStart --columns not using aggregate functions
order by IntervalStart asc, dIntervalStart desc
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause of the OP query; perhaps you could elaborate on what the problem is.

Comment: Seems you have solved it, the error message was about group by. I'm not very familiar with mysql (coming from oracle/sql server) and the group by is not that permissive (alias,etc). Great job my friend.

Comment: Haha didn't see your edit about the group by, thank you that explains a lot for me :)

Comment: you're exactly right that Oracle, SQL Server, et al. would pitch a fit (throw an error) with non-aggregates in the SELECT list that aren't in the GROUP BY clause. (Oracle does allow for literals, and deterministic functions in the SELECT list, when the optimizer can determine that the GROUP BY has those expressions covered.)